# jQuery testing a variable value within a keypress

Tags: jquery

I'm using keyboard values firstly to select a language (2), and then test if that is true upon another keyboard press (1) - My alert function doesn't work as expected - Any ideas why?

Full fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/vh9ho7uc/8/

```
var welshScore = 0;
var englishScore = 0;
var videoScore = 0;

$(".welsh").html(welshScore);
$(".english").html(englishScore);
$(".video").html(videoScore);

$(document).keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 87) {
        var welshScore = 1;
        var englishScore = 0;
        $(".welsh").html(welshScore);
        $(".english").html(englishScore);
    }
    if (event.keyCode === 69) {
        var welshScore = 0;
        var englishScore = 1;
        $(".welsh").html(welshScore);
        $(".english").html(englishScore);
    }

    if(event.keyCode === 49) {
        if(welshScore == 1){
            alert("why is this not working?")
        }       
        var videoScore = 1;
        $(".video").html(videoScore);
    }
    if(event.keyCode === 50) {
        var videoScore = 2;
        $(".video").html(videoScore);
    }
    if(event.keyCode === 51) {
        var videoScore = 3;
        $(".video").html(videoScore);
    }
    if(event.keyCode === 52) {
        var videoScore = 4;
        $(".video").html(videoScore);
    }
});
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it....

```
    if(event.keyCode === 49) {
        if(welshScore = 1){
            alert("yay!");
        } else {
            alert("nay!");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `event.keyCode === 49` to see if you press the <kbd>1</kbd> key

```js
// set variables and apply to paragraph class
var english = 0;
$(".english").html(english);

// if you press 'e' on the keyboard change value
$(document).keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 69) {
        english = 1;
        $(".english").html(english);
    }    

    // if you press 1 on the keyboard
    if (event.keyCode === 49) { 
        if(english == 1){
            alert("English is true and you have pressed 1");
        }   
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="english"></div>
```

Comment: Apologies - that was how it was - I have updated the above question

Comment: The alert doesn't run

Comment: Works fine for me, make sure your jquery is loaded correctly

Answer (score 0):

Use `==` instead of `===`

```js
// set variables and apply to paragraph class
var english = 0;
$(".english").html(english);

// if you press 'e' on the keyboard change value
$(window).keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 69) {
        english = 1;
        $(".english").html(english);
    }    

    // if you press 1 on the keyboard
    if (event.keyCode == 49) { 
        if(english == 1){
            alert("English is true and you have pressed 1");
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="english"></div>
```

Comment: Run the code snippet, press `e` than `1` (not in the numpad!!!) and the alert shows....

Comment: Thanks - I've updated my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vh9ho7uc/8/ - still doesn't work for me?